# Deep Learning binary case : visualization of masks predicted by the model + BinaryIoU

Tags: deep-learning, binary, overlay, inference, semantic-segmentation

I have a question regarding the visualization of masks predicted by the model in a case where we have only one class of object (binary situation). My objective is to import the trained model and visualize the predicted masks on the first images of my training dataset to understand what the model is capable of doing.

However, currently, the model's predictions are in the format of logits, which represent continuous values. To correctly interpret these results, I understood that they need to be converted into probability values (using the sigmoid function, perhaps?). So, I'm looking to create an "inference" function that will transform the logits into probabilities and decide that if the probabilities are greater than 0.5, we consider the pixel to belong to the target class (object), otherwise, we consider it as part of the background (I believe that's how it generally works).

Here is my code that allows training the model:

```
# https://keras.io/examples/vision/deeplabv3_plus/ 
import os
import cv2
import random
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from scipy.io import loadmat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import BinaryIoU

# Creating a TensorFlow Dataset 
# Configuration Variables
IMAGE_SIZE = 512 # resize the images
BATCH_SIZE = 5 # takes 4 samples and trains the network again and again (5 by 5)
NUM_CLASSES = 1
DATA_DIR = r"C:\Users\lscamill\Desktop\SEMANTIC_IA\instance-level-human-parsing\instance-level_human_parsing\instance-level_human_parsing\Training"
NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES = 1382 # for training
NUM_VAL_IMAGES = 346 # for validation

# Data Loading
image_paths = sorted(glob(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "Images2/*")))
mask_paths = sorted(glob(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "mask_final/*")))

combined = list(zip(image_paths, mask_paths))
random.shuffle(combined)
image_paths[:], mask_paths[:] = zip(*combined)

train_images = image_paths[:NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES]
train_masks = mask_paths[:NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES]
val_images = image_paths[NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES:NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES + NUM_VAL_IMAGES]
val_masks = mask_paths[NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES:NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES + NUM_VAL_IMAGES]

# Image Reading and Preprocessing
def read_image(image_path, mask=False):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    if mask: # mask is set to True, the image is treated as a mask image and decoded with a single channel
        image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=1) # or decode_jpeg (grayscale image)
        image.set_shape([None, None, 1])
        image = tf.image.resize(images=image, size=[IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE])
    else:
        image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=3) # or decode_jpeg (channels=3 rgb)
        image.set_shape([None, None, 3])
        image = tf.image.resize(images=image, size=[IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE])
        #  preprocessing step applied to the non-mask (regular) images
        # according to the requirements of the ResNet50 model
        image = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(image)
    return image

# Data Loading and Processing
# loads an image and its corresponding mask
def load_data(image_list, mask_list):
    image = read_image(image_list)
    mask = read_image(mask_list, mask=True)
    return image, mask

# creates a TensorFlow dataset from the image and mask lists ensuring parallel processing)
def data_generator(image_list, mask_list):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_list, mask_list))
    dataset = dataset.map(load_data, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
    return dataset

train_dataset = data_generator(train_images, train_masks)
val_dataset = data_generator(val_images, val_masks)

# Building the DeepLabV3+ model 
# combines a convolutional layer, batch normalization, and ReLU activation to apply non-linear transformations to the input tensor
def convolution_block(
    block_input, #The input tensor to the convolutional block
    num_filters=256,
    kernel_size=3, # The size of the convolutional kernel. Default is 3x3
    dilation_rate=1, #Default =>1 no dilation
    padding="same",
    use_bias=False,
): # 2D convolution on the input tensor using the specified parameters
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        num_filters,
        kernel_size=kernel_size,
        dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
        padding="same",
        use_bias=use_bias,
        kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.HeNormal(),
    )(block_input)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x) # normalizes the activations of the previous layer
    return tf.nn.relu(x) # applied to the normalized tensor

# dilated spatial pyramid pooling by applying average pooling, upsampling, and concatenation operations
def DilatedSpatialPyramidPooling(dspp_input):
    dims = dspp_input.shape # calculating the dimensions of the dspp_input
    x = layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(dims[-3], dims[-2]))(dspp_input) # performs average pooling on the input tensor, reducing its spatial dimensions
    x = convolution_block(x, kernel_size=1, use_bias=True)
    # upsample the tensor x to the original spatial dimensions of the input tensor
    out_pool = layers.UpSampling2D(
        size=(dims[-3] // x.shape[1], dims[-2] // x.shape[2]), interpolation="bilinear",
    )(x)

    out_1 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=1, dilation_rate=1)
    out_6 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=6)
    out_12 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=12)
    out_18 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=18)

    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([out_pool, out_1, out_6, out_12, out_18])
    output = convolution_block(x, kernel_size=1)
    return output

# constructs the DeepLabV3+ model by combining a modified ResNet50 backbone, 
# dilated spatial pyramid pooling, and multi-scale feature fusion
def DeeplabV3Plus(image_size, num_classes):
    model_input = keras.Input(shape=(image_size, image_size, 3))
    resnet50 = keras.applications.ResNet50(
        weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor=model_input
    )
    x = resnet50.get_layer("conv4_block6_2_relu").output
    x = DilatedSpatialPyramidPooling(x)

    input_a = layers.UpSampling2D(
        size=(image_size // 4 // x.shape[1], image_size // 4 // x.shape[2]),
        interpolation="bilinear",
    )(x)
    input_b = resnet50.get_layer("conv2_block3_2_relu").output
    input_b = convolution_block(input_b, num_filters=48, kernel_size=1)

    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([input_a, input_b])
    x = convolution_block(x)
    x = convolution_block(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D(
        size=(image_size // x.shape[1], image_size // x.shape[2]),
        interpolation="bilinear",
    )(x)
    model_output = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same")(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=model_output)


model = DeeplabV3Plus(image_size=IMAGE_SIZE, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)

# Training 
loss = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)  
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss=loss, metrics=[BinaryIoU()])

history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=25)
model.save(r"C:\Users\lscamill\Desktop\new")
plt.plot(history.history["loss"])
plt.title("Training Loss new")
plt.ylabel("loss")
plt.xlabel("epoch")
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history["binary_io_u"])  # Update the key to 'binary_io_u'
plt.title("Training IoU new")
plt.ylabel("IoU")
plt.xlabel("Epoch")
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history["val_loss"])
plt.title("Validation Loss new")
plt.ylabel("val_loss")
plt.xlabel("epoch")
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history["val_binary_io_u"])  # Update the key to 'val_binary_io_u'
plt.title("Validation IoU new")
plt.ylabel("IoU")
plt.xlabel("Epoch")
plt.show()
```

I tried these but i obtain only value between 0,001 et 0,009 (very low probability - it may be normal since my model does not have a lot of images to train):

```
model = keras.models.load_model(r"C:\Users\lscamill\Desktop\new")
model.layers[-1].activation = tf.keras.activations.sigmoid

def infer(model, image_tensor):
    predictions = model.predict(np.expand_dims((image_tensor), axis=0)) 
    predictions = np.squeeze(predictions) # This line removes unnecessary dimensions from the predictions.
    prediction_binary = predictions > 0.5
    return prediction_binary # array that contains the predicted segmentation mask
```

Moreover, when I look at my IoU plots for training and validation I have values around 0.49 (so it's acceptable) but when I try to look at the predictions generated for the same images they are low so is there a problem somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I think that to convert your output logits to a probability for each class (for each pixel), you need to apply a `Softmax` function across the channels dimension. `Softmax` rescales the values such that they are positive and *add up to 1* - `sigmoid` only makes them positive and therefore cannot be interpreted as a probability.

If you choose any pixel, and move along the channels dimension for that pixel, the softmax value along the axis tell you the probability for that channel. For each pixel, you can identify the channel that scored the highest probability by applying an `argmax` function along the channel dimension (for binary this is equivalent to scoring probability>0.5). This new map might correct the IoU behaviour you're seeing.

```
#logits size: [batch, h, w, channels]
logits = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same")(x)

#probabilities size: [batch, h, w, channels]
probabilities = layers.Softmax(dim=-1)(logits)

#Segmentation map size: [batch, h, w] (or [batch, h, w, 1])
#Each pixel has a value identifying the channel index that scored highest
#For binary case this is equivalent to scoring > 0.5
highest_scoring_channels = probabilities.argmax(dim=-1)
```

Adapted for your `infer` method, the code would look like this:

```py
model = keras.models.load_model(r"C:\Users\lscamill\Desktop\new")

#deleted the sigmoid line

def infer(model, image_tensor):
    #Your model returns logits, as done originally. i.e. model hasn't changed.
    model_output = model.predict(np.expand_dims((image_tensor), axis=0))

    #Convert model_output (which are logits) to probabilities
    probabilities = layers.Softmax(dim=-1)(model_output)

    #Convert to a binary segmentation mask per class
    predicted_class0 = probabilities[:, :, :, 0] > 0.5
    predicted_class1 = probabilities[:, :, :, 1] > 0.5
    
    #Return the desired segmentation mask
    return predicted_class0
```

Comment: Oh I need to do this directly in the model and not after it's too late I guess?

Comment: Your model should stay the same, i.e. it should still return logits because the loss function you're using expects logits. When it comes to your `infer` function, you should take the model's output as before, and then apply softmax along the channels dimension. That'll convert the model's logit outputs to probabilities, which you can then threshold, view as an image, calculate IoU, etc.

Comment: okay but i don t understand where i have to put : #logits size: [batch, h, w, channels]
logits = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same")(x)

#probabilities size: [batch, h, w, channels]
probabilities = layers.Softmax(dim=-1)(logits) I suppose the rest is in infer

Comment: I have edited my original answer above to include example code for the `infer` method - does that help?

Comment: it seems to work with this, thanks : def infer(model, image_tensor):
    # Your model returns logits, as done originally. i.e. model hasn't changed.
    model_output = model.predict(np.expand_dims(image_tensor, axis=0))

    # Convert model_output (which are logits) to probabilities
    probabilities = layers.Softmax(axis=-1)(model_output)

    # Convert to a binary segmentation mask
    predicted_class = probabilities[:, :, :, 0] > 0.5

    # Return the desired segmentation mask
    return predicted_class

Comment: When i calculate BinaryIoU next i obtained mean of 0.028058242 whereas during the training BinaryIoU was more around 0,49. Is it normal ?

Comment: It looks like your train score is better than your test score which is expected. In this case the gap between them seems large, suggesting the model is overfitting, unless something else is wrong. How bad are your test results, visually? To confirm the model is learning ok, I would plot train loss vs epoch & confirm the train loss goes down each epoch. It's helpful to also plot *test* loss vs epoch, and see how it tracks train loss. If the model is overfitting, you'll find that the train & test loss start together, then they go down, until at some point the test loss flatlines/swings back up.

Comment: When I plot the loss of training over 30 epochs I see that it decreases from 0.1387 to 0.1059 (it's low), with regard to validation it fluctuates stagnating around 0.15 with a few peaks at 0.28 ( era 3). When I plot IoU for training it stagnates until epoch 20 then increases (0.4949 to 0.5404) (I think the model doesn't really learn anymore and just memorizes since the IoU validation stagnates (0.4933)). I conclude that I have an overfitting problem. Moreover, I think I am wrong in my way of visualizing the results because in fact I find the same IoU values.

Comment: So either binary IoU is not displaying the correct values, or it is my way of converting logits to proba that is wrong (it would have to be done the same way BinaryIoU does I imagine). Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: No problem. I think there are two things to consider - the loss, and the IoU. Since the model is directly optimising the loss, plotting the loss (rather than the IoU) will provide a picture of the model's convergence behaviour. The IoU on the other hand is more about how useful the model has become for your task. If you think the IoU computation might be wrong, consider just looking at loss first. Decreasing loss (better model convergence) should roughly give you an increasing IoU (model becomes better at the task). Just some thoughts. Sounds like you're on track to identify issues.